# Can't include glib library in my CMakeLists.txt - undefined reference

Tags: cmake, glib

I installed `glib2.0` library on my Linux distribution through `sudo apt-get install libglib2.0`. The library has been installed at `/usr/include/glib-2.0`. At this point, I prepared a very dummy C project that uses that library and tried to include it through a *CMakeLists.txt* (I report it for the sake of completeness):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <glib.h>
int main(){
    GList* list = NULL;
    list = g_list_append(list, "Hello world!");
    printf("The first item is '%s'\n", (char*)g_list_first(list)->data);
    return 0;
}
```

The *CMakeLists.txt* is:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.4.3)
project(test)

find_package(PkgConfig REQUIRED)
pkg_check_modules(GLIB_PKG glib-2.0)

if (GLIB_PKG_FOUND)
    message(Found glib-2.0)
endif (GLIB_PKG_FOUND)
add_executable(basic src/main.c)

target_include_directories(basic PRIVATE ${GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${GLIB_PKG_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(basic ${GLIB_LIBRARIES})
```

The folders organization is the following:

1. ./CMakeLists.txt
2. ./src/main.cpp
3. ./build/"here `cmake ..` is executed"

The `cmake ..` gives no error, but, when i run `make`, this errors come up:

```
[ 50%] Building C object CMakeFiles/basic.dir/src/main.o
[100%] Linking C executable basic
CMakeFiles/basic.dir/src/main.o: In function `main':
main.c:(.text+0x1d): undefined reference to `g_list_append'
main.c:(.text+0x2d): undefined reference to `g_list_first'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/basic.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'basic' failed
make[2]: *** [basic] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/basic.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/basic.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: You call `pkg_check_modules` with `GLIB_PKG` argument, so it creates variables with that prefix. You use correct `GLIB_PKG_INCLUDE_DIRS` in one place, but two other places use **wrong variables** `GLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS` and `GLIB_LIBRARIES`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks, thanks and thanks. I'm really new at using CMake..